# Copying nested custom objects: alternatives to deepcopy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to make a deep copy of a class object that contains a list of class objects, each with their own set of stuff. The objects don't contain anything more exciting than ints and lists (no dicts, no generators waiting to yield, etc). I'm performing the deep copy on between 500-800 objects a loop, and it's really slowing the program down. I realize that this is already inefficient; it currently can't be changed.

Example of how it looks:

```
import random
import copy

class Base:
    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, length):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.numbers = [random.randint(minimum, maximum) for _ in range(length)]
        # etc

class Next:
    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, length, quantity):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.bases = [Base(minimum, maximum, length) for _ in range(quantity)]
        # etc
```

Because of the actions I'm performing on the objects, I can't shallow copy. I need the contents to be owned by the new variable:

```
> first = Next(0, 10, 5, 10)
> second = first
> first.bases[0].numbers[1] = 4
> print(first.bases[0].numbers)
> [2, 4, 3, 3, 8]
> print(second.bases[0].numbers)
> [2, 4, 3, 3, 8]
>
> first = Next(0, 10, 5, 10)
> second = copy.deepcopy(first)
> first.bases[0].numbers[1] = 4
> print(first.bases[0].numbers)
> [8, 4, 7, 9, 9]
> print(second.bases[0].numbers)
> [8, 11, 7, 9, 9]
```

I've tried a couple of different ways, such as using json to serialize and reload the data, but in my tests it's not been nearly fast enough, because I'm stuck reassigning all of the variables each time. My attempt at pulling off a clever `self.__dict__ = dct` hasn't worked because of the nested objects.

Any ideas for how to efficiently deep copy multiply-nested Python objects without using copy.deepcopy?

Comment: You might want to think about ways of storing your data items as primitives (e.g. ints and strings) rather than Python objects.  Copying those would be far more efficient.  Perhaps the array module or even the cython language would be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on cherish's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756712/deepcopy-is-extremely-slow/29385667#29385667), `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(first))` works about twice as fast per call. I had written it off initially because of an unrelated error when testing it, but on retesting it, it performs well within my needs.

Answer (score 5):

One of the first things that `copy.deepcopy` looks for is if the object defines [it's own `__deepcopy__` method](https://github.com/tadhgmister/cpython/blob/master/Lib/copy.py#L159) So instead of having it figure out how to copy object every time just define your own process.

It would require you have a way of defining a `Base` object without any element of random-ness for the copies to use, but if you can find a more efficient process of copying your objects you should define it as a `__deepcopy__` method to speed up copying process.

Comment: I'm not sure how much a custom `__deepcopy__` can help here. The default implementation already copies all attributes, and it avoids calling `__init__` on the new object, so you don't run into any problems with the random stuff. I think the only clear ways to improve performance is to either dramatically change the data structures (e.g. using `numpy` arrays or something, rather than lists of objects), or changing the whole algorithm to avoid the need for all the copying.

Comment: I tried this out, and couldn't get the speed gains I was hoping for (no doubt an error on my part in how I implemented it). I found that using `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(first))` worked about twice as fast as deepcopy for my purposes. Thanks for the help!