# Copying a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, nested-lists

I am working with (lists of) lists of numpy arrays. As a bare bones example, consider this piece of code:

```
a = [np.zeros(5)]
b = a.copy()
b[0] += 1
```

Here, I copy a list of one array from `a` to `b`. However, the array itself is not copied, so:

```
print(a)
print(b)
```

both give `[array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])]`. If I want to make a copy of the array as well, I could do something like:

```
b = [arr.copy() for arr in a]
```

and `a` would remain unchanged. This works well for a simple list, but it becomes more complicated when working with nested lists of arrays where the number of arrays in each list is not always the same.

Is there a simple way to copy a multi-level list and every object that it contains without keeping references to the objects in the original list? Basically, I would like to avoid nested loops as well as dealing with the size of each individual sub-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a deepcopy

```
import numpy as np
import copy
a = [np.zeros(5)]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b[0] += 1  # a[0] is not changed
```

This is actually method recommended in [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) for the deepcopy of `object` arrays.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I guess this solution would work as well with, say, a custom class that contains other objects such as arrays?

Comment: Yes it should indeed, more about alternatives to deepcopy for custom objects here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028978/copying-nested-custom-objects-alternatives-to-deepcopy

Answer (score 1):

You need to use deepcopy.

```
import numpy as np
import copy

a = [np.zeros(5)]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b[0] += 1

print(a)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]
[array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])]
```