# Why is Python's deepcopy() of a class-object sharing class-variables?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I'm using deepcopy to make a deep copy of a Python class, and change the class variable of the copied object.  For some reason, the class variable of the original class that was copied is also being changed.  Why is this?

It doesn't seem to happen when I create a class with the ['type' syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

```
import copy

class Test:
    a = 0

print(Test.a) # 0
b = copy.deepcopy(Test)
b.a = 1
print(Test.a) # 1 - why?

c = type('Test2', (Test,), {'a': 2})
print(Test.a) # still 1
```

Comment: This is a static class variable, not an instance variable. Make an instance of the class first with a `self` variable, then copy it and you'll get your desired result on the `self` variable. As an aside, `deepcopy` is [super](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62865237/6243352) [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756712/deepcopy-is-extremely-slow). Probably don't use it, or if you do, implement `__deepcopy__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your first question:**

As pointed out by @Blckknght in the comments, when you pass a class-definition object to `copy.deepcopy()`, you run into a behavior of `deepcopy()` that is surprising / quirky, though intentional -- instead of making a deep copy of the class-definition object, `deepcopy()` merely returns a **reference to the same class-definition object**.

To verify this,

```
print ("b is:", b)
b_instance = b()
print ("b is Test ?:", (b is Test))
```

gives:

```
b is: <class '__main__.Test'>
b is Test ?: True             # deepcopy() hasn't made a copy at all !
```

Here's what [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) says regarding `deepcopy()` for class-definition objects:

> This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace,
> stack frame, file, socket, window, array, or any similar types. It
> does “copy” functions and classes (shallow and deeply), by returning
> the original object unchanged; this is compatible with the way these
> are treated by the pickle module.

So, when you do

```
b.a = 1
```

you're still modifying the class variable of the class `Test`.

**Your second question:**

When you do

```
c = type('Test2', (Test,), {'a': 2})
```

you *are* creating a new type called `Test2`, with its own class variable called `a`, and having `Test` as its superclass.

Now `Test2.a` and `Test.a` are two different class variables, defined in two different classes, and can take values independently of each other. One is a class variable called `a` in the superclass `Test`, the other is a class variable with the same name `a` in the subclass `Test2`.

That is why `c.a` will give `2` (the value to which you initialized it), and `Test.a` will continue to give `1`

Comment: You might want your initial code block to test `b is Test`. The things you're currently doing don't conclusively show that `deepcopy` is a no-op for class objects. You sort of say that, but don't explain that this is somewhat unusual. Generally `deepcopy` *does* create a new object containing the same things, but it doesn't do so for classes (this is a design decision made by the developers of Python, not an absolute thing that couldn't have been designed another way).

Comment: @Blckknght, agree with your first point, and edited my answer, thanks. Your second point is that `deepcopy()` isn't doing a sincere copy in the case of class objects. I'm not sure about that. The observations that we're trying to rationalize here seem to indicate that `deepcopy()` **is** in fact doing **too good a job** of copying. So, instead of creating a class object for an entirely newly class, it is creating a class object that describes the exact same class `Test` -- which is what a proper copy-operation would be expected to do

Comment: There's no copy of `Test` being done at all. `b = copy.deepcopy(Test)` is equivalent to `b = Test`, it's just binding a new name to the existing class object.

Comment: @Blckknght, I get your point, updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: the term is just "class object" or "class", not "class definition object".

Answer (score 0):

You copied the class definition and not the instance itself.

You should be doing something like this instead:

```
import copy

class Test:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

test1 = Test(0)
test2 = copy.deepcopy(test1)

print("Original:")
print("Test 1: " + str(test1.a)) #0
print("Test 2: " + str(test2.a)) #0

print("Modify test 2 to 10")
test2.a = 10
print("Test 1: " + str(test1.a)) #0
print("Test 2: " + str(test2.a)) #10
```

> Original:
>
> Test 1: 0
>
> Test 2: 0
>
> Modify test 2 to 10
>
> Test 1: 0
>
> Test 2: 10

Comment: thanks Jackson.  Due to limitations of what I'm using this for (SQLAlchemy mixins), I had to copy the class itself, not the instance of the class (as that's not something my code itself handles).